# App get crashed when FUIButton is tapped

Tags: ios

I'm using FlatUIKit to custom my own buttons. But when button is tapped , app get crashed.
I have the following codes just the same as the example code of FlatUIKit. I have tried to install it via CocoaPods or added it manually.

```
FUIButton *myButton = [[FUIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 340, 240, 60)];
myButton.buttonColor = [UIColor turquoiseColor];
myButton.shadowColor = [UIColor greenSeaColor];
myButton.shadowHeight = 3.0f;
myButton.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:16];
[myButton setTitle:@"hahahaahhhahah" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor cloudsColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(weiboLoginAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Here is the crash log in iOS 6:

`2014-09-04 15:47:13.298 comChat[37118:907] -[UICFFont weiboLoginAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a914e0`

In iOS 7 , there is no crash log.

Comment: Whats the crash message/stack trace ?

Comment: Are you sure the class you're showing has a method called `weiboLoginAction:`? (And that it takes exactly one argument?)

Comment: I have no idea. `[xxxxxx weiboLoginAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a914e0`, xxxxxx is different every time.

Comment: I'm sure `weiboLoginAction:` method exists in the class.

Comment: Looks like your class is being deallocated and it's memory is being reused for a UIFont. Figure out where you have a memory leak and fix it.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin,I have used Instrument to checkout memory leak. And it  did have memory leak problem .